# .htaccess in parent directory causing ErrorDocument in subdirectory to not work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a subdirectory that points to its own domain, so I want it to have its own 404 page. The .htaccess in the subdirectory reads:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/404.html
```

I feel like this should work, but there's a problem. The parent directory has an install of wordpress, so the .htaccess is as follows

```
# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# Set PHP handler to application/x-httpd-phpbeta on Mon Jan 11 15:10:53 MST 2016.
```

**If there is an index.php in the subdirectory, that is used as the 404 page.** Otherwise, I get a 500 error, whether or not the .htaccess in the subfolder is even present.  What's stopping my .htaccess from working?

Comment: Does the custom error message work? try **ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry the page not found"**

Comment: No, I still get a 404. Sucks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `RewriteEngine On` line in `/subdirectory/.htaccess` to override rewrite rules of parent directory. Your `/subdirectory/.htaccess` would become this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/404.html

RewriteEngine On
```